# Calling one function on another activity

Tags: android, function, call

I have created a function

```
public void setTabHome(int index) {  }
```

on **main.java** page. This function is to set the page by index.

By default, index is **0**. I want to **call main.java page from main1.java** with the parameter `index` set to **1**.

Comment: why can't you create it in main1.java?

Comment: main1.java page is the next activity page.

Comment: I have called like this,
 Main main= new Main();
 main.setTabHome(1);

Answer (score 0):

You can set the method to static and then call it again.

I would just insert that method again in main1.java though ¯_(ツ)_/¯

or even better access main1.java through an Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Make an instance of your `main.java` class in `main1.java` class. Using this instance, you can call the function in `main.java`. Like this

```
Main main = new Main();
main.yourfunctionName();
```

But better you make another function in `main1.java` and use this function. Beacuse the parameters you used in one activity may cannot be used in another activity.

Comment: I have called like this,
 Main main= new Main();
 main.setTabHome(1);

But it does not redirect to that function.

Comment: what do you want to do with the function??

Answer (score 0):

1. `public static void setTabHome(int index) {  }`
2. `main.setTabHome(indexnumber)`

Comment: I cannot modify that function to static

Answer (score 0):

main.java define a public static instance in the class

```
    public class Menu extends Activity{

        public static Menu instance = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
             instance = this;
        }

        public void setTabHome(int index) { }
    }
```

main1.java call like this:

```
     Menu.instance.setTabHome(number);
```